# NosuchFileException found when compose up docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I have have the following error when compose up the container.

```
mirror-maker  | 360 [main] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory  - Modification time of key store could not be obtained: "/etc/tmp/key
store.jks"
mirror-maker  | java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: "/etc/tmp/keystore.jks"
```

I exec into the container and found the file does exit with permission 644.

> -rw-r--r--. 1 appuser appuser   3358 Sep 26 16:10 keystore.jks

Here is how I firstly mount and access the volume in docker compose file.

```
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/kafka-mirror-maker/configs:/etc/tmp
environment:
    CONNECT_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION="/etc/tmp/keystore.jks"
```

I tested using docker run command which worked surprisely.

```
docker run -d -v /home/ec2-user/kafka-mirror-maker/configs:/etc/tmp \
-e CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION="/etc/tmp/keystore.jks" \
```

Then I tried to use named volume and it did not work either.

```
    volumes:
      - configs:/etc/tmp

volumes:
  configs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /home/ec2-user/kafka-mirror-maker/configs
```

Thanks in advance!